# raw text data to dictionary key, value with tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and struggling with this data and structure I want to create. I have to create a key, value dictionary from raw text. 
Reading text line by line and placing values in proper keys.

I am getting into various challenges first how to deal with raw text correctly, and secondly how to manage and create my dictionary in a proper way. Any assistance will be appreciated

For instance:

Here is the snippet of raw data I have:

```
Ready Player One (2018)
140 min
-
Action
|
Adventure
|
Sci-Fi
User Rating: 7.9/10 (70,757 user ratings)
64
Metascore
|
Rank:
1
Showtimes:
Get Tickets
1:20 pm
|
7:50
Showtimes 3D:
Get Tickets
10:00 am
|
4:35 pm
|
11:00
Showtimes 3D, IMAX:
Get Tickets
12:15 pm
|
3:30
|
7:00
|
10:30
The Miracle Season (2018)
101 min
-
Drama
|
Sport
User Rating: 6.3/10 (190 user ratings)
44
Metascore
|
Rank:
< 500
Showtimes:
Get Tickets
11:05 am
|
1:40 pm
|
4:25
|
7:15
|
10:10
```

I would like to create a following dictionary as output:

Please note Movie theater 1 is coming from variable for example

```
movie_theater1='Movie Theater 1'

output={"Ready Player One (2018)":"Movie theater 1,140min,Action|Adventure|Sci-Fi,User Rating: 7.9,Metascore:64,Showtimes:1:20 pm|7:50-Showtimes 3D:10:00 am|4:35 pm|11:00-Showtimes 3D, IMAX:12:15 pm|3:30|7:00|10:30",
"The Miracle Season (2018)":"Movie theater 1,101 min,Drama|Sport,User Rating: 6.3,Metascore:44,Showtimes:11:05 am|1:40 pm|4:25|7:15|10:10"}
```

Comment: You would need some kind of identifier in your text which would tell you when a new movie title has appeared. Otherwise the computer won't be able to differentiate between a new movie entry, or just another parameter that goes into the last entry.

Comment: (2018) or (yyyy) identifier will be consistent

Comment: ok that's good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach:

Logic is whenever regex pattern appear , Empty the list and append from start.

if you want more good result , you have to clean the string output before appending like `replace('-','')`  , I am leaving that upon you.

```
import re

pattern=r'\w.+(?=\([0-9]{4})'


movie_details=[]
movie_name=[]
final_dict={}
with open('wa','r') as f:
    def regex_approach():

        sub_details=[]
        for line in f:
            if re.search(pattern,line):
                movie_name.append(re.search(pattern,line).group())
                if sub_details:
                    movie_details.append(sub_details)
                sub_details=[]
            else:
                sub_details.append(line.strip())
        movie_details.append(sub_details)

    regex_approach()

print(dict(zip(movie_name,movie_details)))
```

output:

```
{'Ready Player One ': ['140 min', '-', 'Action', '|', 'Adventure', '|', 'Sci-Fi', 'User Rating: 7.9/10 (70,757 user ratings)', '64', 'Metascore', '|', 'Rank:', '1', 'Showtimes:', 'Get Tickets', '1:20 pm', '|', '7:50', 'Showtimes 3D:', 'Get Tickets', '10:00 am', '|', '4:35 pm', '|', '11:00', 'Showtimes 3D, IMAX:', 'Get Tickets', '12:15 pm', '|', '3:30', '|', '7:00', '|', '10:30'], 'The Miracle Season ': ['101 min', '-', 'Drama', '|', 'Sport', 'User Rating: 6.3/10 (190 user ratings)', '44', 'Metascore', '|', 'Rank:', '< 500', 'Showtimes:', 'Get Tickets', '11:05 am', '|', '1:40 pm', '|', '4:25', '|', '7:15', '|', '10:10']}
```

Comment: Hi Paul, I am testing this algorithm, two questions, 1) if I have theater = 'Movie theater 2' and if movie name it same will this append movie details from Movie theater 2 for that movie? Example {"Movie 1": "Movie Theater 1 details, Movie Theater 2 details", "Movie 2": "Movie Theater 1 details, Movie Theater 2 details"} 2) I am getting '' empty elements in movie_details I would like to clean that up list(set) is not working any suggestions?

Comment: I do not suggest answering this user's questions. All he wants, apparently, is to make you code for him without slightest understanding of Python on his side. You can look at his history and comments below my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of badly structured data you need to write a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). For example like this:

```
import re

re_movie_title = re.compile('^.*\((19\d\d|20[012]\d)\)$')
re_rating = re.compile('^User Rating: (\d(\.\d+)?)')
re_number = re.compile('^\d+$')

theater = 'Movie theater 1'
data = {}

# State variables
movie = None
genres = False
last_line = ''
ignore = 0          # how many lines to ignore
tickets = False

for line in open('movie.dat'):
    line = line.strip()
    if re_movie_title.search(line):
        movie = line
        data[movie] = theater
        tickets = False
    elif line == '-':
        genres = True
        data[movie] += ','
    elif re_rating.search(line):
        genres = False
        data[movie] += ',' + re_rating.search(line).group(0)
    elif genres:
        data[movie] += line
    elif line=='Metascore':
        data[movie] += ',' + line + ':' + last_line
        ignore = 3
    elif ignore:
        ignore -= 1
    elif re_number.search(line):
        pass
    elif line == 'Get Tickets':
        tickets = True
    elif line[-1]==':':
        if ',' not in line:
            data[movie] += ','+line
        else:
            data[movie] += '-'+line
    elif tickets:
        data[movie] += line
    else:
        data[movie] += ','+line
    last_line = line

print (data)
```

It assumes that your raw data is saved in file `movie.dat`.

Output:

```
{'Ready Player One (2018)': 'Movie theater 1,140 min,Action|Adventure|Sci-Fi,User Rating: 7.9,Metascore:64,Showtimes:1:20 pm|7:50,Showtimes 3D:10:00 am|4:35 pm|11:00-Showtimes 3D, IMAX:12:15 pm|3:30|7:00|10:30', 'The Miracle Season (2018)': 'Movie theater 1,101 min,Drama|Sport,User Rating: 6.3,Metascore:44,Showtimes:11:05 am|1:40 pm|4:25|7:15|10:10'}
```

The output almost matches your desired output.

Comment: State machine interesting concept, can you please explain little more on this implementation. Just high-level details will be appreciated. Looks very genius

Comment: @spider22, it's actually very easy. There are a number of state variables like `genres` and `tickets`. Values of those variables change the behavior of the program.  For example, each time we meet a line `-`, we know that the following lines will be movie genres, so we  set `genres = True`. And while `genres == True` we just append each line to the output until we meet `User Rating:` line, and so on. When we are in state `tickets == True` we also append each new line to output without comma, unless a line ends with `:`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Andriy Mukakha, thanks for the explanation, one question I have if I have theater = 'Movie theater 2' and if movie name it same will this append movie details from Movie theater 2 for that movie? Example {"Movie 1": "Movie Theater 1 details, Movie Theater 2 details", "Movie 2": "Movie Theater 1 details, Movie Theater 2 details"}

Comment: No, it will not append. If you want it to append every time it finds the same movie, you need to change `data[movie] = theater` to something like `data[movie] = (data[movie] + '\n' if movie in data else '') + theater`.

Comment: Andriy Mukakha, did the change but it didn't work? Any other suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work? :) I've just tried it and it worked exactly as I wanted it to. What exactly doesn't work for you?

Comment: Andriy Mukakha, I am sorry my bad, it did work!! thanks!

Comment: Andriy Mukakha, there is one problem with the code that, when I read the file for Movie Theater 1 it populates the dictionary with values (for example showtimes), however, when the second time I run for Movie Theater 2 it populates the shows for Movies Theater 1 and Movies Theater 2. This way I have duplicate for Movie Theater 2 with Showtimes for Movies Theater 1. Any thoughts on making sure when you read the showtimes once skip that next time OR should I create clean up function to delete duplicate entries

Comment: Andriy Mukakha, will it be possible to declare multiple values for a key like this

 data = {
    'key1': 'value',
    'key2': ['value1', 'value2'],
}

Comment: @spider22, anything is possible. Instead of `data[movie] = theater` you would have `data[movie] = {}; data[movie]['theater'] = theater` and so on. I must say, you have picked a wrong approach to learning Python and programming. You need to start from the beginning: study some Python tutorial, learn basic algorithms. Then you will be able to write your own complex parsers, read and modify others' code.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, with this change data[movie] = {}; data[movie]['theater'] = theater getting error: data[movie] += ','+line
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'dict' and 'str'

Comment: Yes, because you need to change the script further accordingly.